# Parameters with Default Values and Variadic Parameters Together

Tags: python, function, variables, variadic-functions, default-value

I'm trying to learn the different special function parameters in Python and get somewhat confused about them.

Consider this function `bar`:

```py
def bar(arg, default_arg = 99, *pos_vari_arg, **kywd_vari_arg):
    print(arg, default_arg, pos_vari_arg, kywd_vari_arg)
```

When I call it by

```
bar(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, foo=5, test=6)
```

It prints

```
0 1 (2, 3, 4) {'foo': 5, 'test': 6}
```

However, I actually want the `default_arg` to just be `99` and pass `1,2,3,4` to `pos_vari_arg`. To achieve this, I tried to access `default_arg` as a keyword parameter instead:

```py
bar(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, foo=5, test=6, default_arg = 99)
```

But that would simply give me a `#TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'default_arg'`, *because Python is not sure whether my `default_arg = 99` should go to the parameter `default_arg` or the dictionary `kywd_vari_arg`*.

I also tried to force `default_arg` to be a keyword-only parameter by inserting a `*,`:

```py
def bar(arg, *, default_arg = 99, *pos_vari_arg, **kywd_vari_arg):
    print(arg, default_arg, pos_vari_arg, kywd_vari_arg)
```

But Python throws an error:

```py
File "<string>", line 1
    def bar(arg, * , default_arg = 99, *pos_vari_arg, **kywd_vari_arg):
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After some research, I found that *`*vari_arg` must be a positional parameter and thus it cannot be placed after the `*,`* and hence the syntax error. I also found that *all parameters after `*vari_arg` would be forced to be keyword-only parameters*, so I do not need the `*,` to do this job. Instead, I can just swap the places of the parameters:

```
def bar(arg, *vari_arg, default_arg = 99, **vari_kwarg):
  print(arg, default_arg, vari_arg, vari_kwarg)
```

Now, `bar(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, foo=5, test=6)` will print `0 99 (1, 2, 3, 4) {'foo': 5, 'test': 6}`, which is what I intended to achieve originally.

Question:

1. Is this the only way to achieve this effect?
2. Are all my understanding correct? Especially sentence in *italic*.
3. What is the best practice to follow if a function has standard
   parameters, parameters with default values, and variadic parameters?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `default_arg`, should that be `kywd_arg`?

Comment: Your final understanding looks like it's correct. Positional and named parameters are always filled in first, and the variable parameters then get the rest.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for noticing. I have corrected this error.

Comment: Try to define this :
```default_arg = None if not 'default_arg' in kywd_vari_arg else kywd_vari_arg['default_arg']```

Comment: You seem to have things right. To break your brain further, Python 3.8+ also allow *positional only* arguments, indicated by following them by a `/` in the argument list. So `foo(a, b, /, c, d)` indicates a function with four arguments, but `a` and `b` can only be passed positionally, not as keywords. That can be useful if you don't want their names to be part of the public API, or to mask other kwargs. See [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/).

Comment: @ThisIsMatin That's a workaround too. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you all for your confirmation!